# Filtering not working in protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba, filtering, protected

I have the code below for protecting one sheet. Sorting works fine, but filtering does not, even though AllowFiltering is True. Are there any suggestions to what is preventing filtering from working?

I have tried setting Userinterfaceonly to true and to false, but neither makes any difference. Likewise EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells does not help.

```
Sub LockCols()

Dim Sh As Worksheet

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    '2 other If/End If statements protecting other sheets

    If Sh.Name = "Combined" Then

            Sh.Activate
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="ABC123"
            ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False 'True prevents sorting and filtering
            ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="ABC123", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, _
                Userinterfaceonly:=True, _
                AllowFiltering:=True, _
                AllowSorting:=True, _
                AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
                AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
                AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
                AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
                AllowFormattingCells:=False, _
                AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
                AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
                AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False

    End If

Next

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I seem to be able to use autofilter in sheet with using this code. I was I supposed to change this line: ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False ?

Comment: Why are you using Activesheet.Protect Password:="ABC123" with filtering code. You can first filter and then use Activesheet.Protect Password:="ABC123" to protect sheet

Comment: @mmehta (psssst - that says "`Unprotect`")   :)

Comment: Can you please define **"`Not Working`"**?  What is the problem, and where?

Comment: Thanks guys - Not working means that filtering is not enabled at all (the Filter button is greyed out). @mmehta Maybe I have misunderstood, but your suggestion implies users have to turn off protection (=need to know the password) to use filtering, but I do not want users to be able to turn off protection.

Comment: @cdfj - once again, what is **Not Working**? You cannot select the cell with the filter, you cannot click on it, the results are wrong?

Comment: To enable the filter you have to unprotect the sheet. But you can unprotect sheet add filter then protect sheet through macro but then filter is of no use.

Comment: @mmehta - I HAVE misunderstood! You are right! Applying filtering and then protecting the sheet has solved the problem! MANY thank yous! This has been driving me crazy!

Comment: Good to know. Kindly mark my answer as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something as small as this one:

```
Sub TestMe()        
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="ABC123", AllowFiltering:=True    
End Sub
```

And see whether it works. If it does, probably there is some problem with the `ActiveSheet` in the loop I guess.

Comment: that's quite a big task (complex workbook), but I will give it a try. I will be gone for some time!

Comment: @cdfj - we will miss you! :)

Comment: thank you! mmehta solution has saved me this painful exercise!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps anybody but if you go into [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.protection.allowfiltering) the AllowFiltering works this way that you have to have the autofilter set up and then protect your worksheet.